# 10 Pin Bowling Score Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been tasked with creating a bowling score calculator in javascript.

I am a complete newbie to javascript so I'm not sure where to start. Are there any simple examples of this specific project I can use as reference?

I keep finding long and convoluted code for it that doesn't make much sense...

Comment: maybe you should learn some javascript first?

Comment: Thats the point of the exercise.

Comment: @enigmacoder If you don't do some re-search and try something on your own... then there is no point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question presented is a bit vague, as it is unclear what platform you are working on, if there is any sort of UI expected or logic only, and a reference for such calculator expected to be written by you could help simplify the answer.

As a general rule of thumb for when stuck with code, I would recommend beginning by structuring the project. Laying out anything that needs to work later.
Will you be requiring more than a few methods/functions? If so, lay out the structure wanted.
As a general example, I'd create a:

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ File           ║  Purpose                                                          ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  calc.html     ║ Main view (if implemented as html). May have a CSS attached to it.║
║  calcView.js   ║ JS view controller. To be used for any logic related to views.    ║
║  calcMain.js   ║ Main JS calculator implementation, to separate calculation logic. ║
║  ops.html(...) ║ Optional options page, other related extras, and so on.           ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Begin by creating empty files, and then start by implementing everything you are certain you will need. Along the process it will be easy to figure out what else is needed.

I'd recommend starting with the main JS, and actually taking the first step of writing:

```
function mainCalculation(input){

return output;
}
```

Then fill it up.
In the process try to figure out what should be separated to its own method, and what is part of this.

This may lead you to something like:

```
function parseRequest(inputRequestObject){
    //  TODO
    return outputRequestData;
}

function calcScore(inputRequestData){
    //  TODO
    return outputAsINT;
}

function generateResponseObject(intScore){
    //  TODO
    return outputObject;
}

function handleRequest(input){

    // This is your main flow of handling a single calculation.
    // Try to include the minimal amount of logic possible here.

    var parsedInput = parseRequest(input);    
    var intScore = calcScore(parsedInput);
    var output = generateResponseObject(intScore);

    // At this point your response might include extra info, and not just intScore.
    // Example: the original request data, or error data, if the client needs it.

    return output;
}
```

Once this model is complete, and you are able to return the result successfully, try to design the UI (if needed), and figure the connection between the two using the view controller.

By the time you get to this point, you will know exactly how to move on to the extra stuff, such as options page, options controller, and so on.

**One last tip:**
You could try and look for more general examples, as your project is very specific.
For example, check [this example](http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/javascript/calc.htm) for creating a Javscript calculator. I dislike the formatting used, but as a basic guide, it is not bad.

If you still feel the need to, go over the great [W3Schools JavaScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/), perfect for starters, and maybe consider going over relevant examples in their [JS Examples page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you can take a look at. This calculates score using a provided string representation of the game.

bowlingScore('11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11'); // 20

```js
function bowlingScore(frames) {
  var framesArr = frames.split(' ').map((frame) => [...frame]);
  var result = 0;
  
  for (var i=0; i < framesArr.length; i++) {
    var current = framesArr[i];
    
    if(current[0] === 'X' && i < 9) {
      result += 10 + getNextElementsScore(framesArr, i, 2);
    } else if(current.length === 2 && current[1] === '/' && i < 9) {
      result += 10 + getNextElementsScore(framesArr, i, 1);
    } else if(current.length === 3) {
      result += getThreeRollScore(current);
    } else {
      result += getElementScore(current, 0) + getElementScore(current, 1);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function getNextElementsScore(framesArr, index, count) {
  var result = getElementScore(framesArr[index + 1], 0);
  var result2 = getElementScore(framesArr[index + 1], 1)
  
  if (framesArr[index + 1].length === 1) {
    return count === 1 ? result : result + getElementScore(framesArr[index + 2], 0);
  }
  return count === 1 ? result : (result2 === 10 && result !== 10 ? result2 : result2 + result );
}
    
function getElementScore(frame, index) {
  if (frame[index] === 'X' || frame[index] === '/') {
    return 10;
  }
  return parseInt(frame[index]);
}

function getThreeRollScore(current) {
  var third = getElementScore(current, 2);
  var second = getElementScore(current, 1);
  var first = getElementScore(current, 0);

  return third === 10 && second !== 10 ? third + first : (second === 10 && first !== 10 ? third + second : first + second + third);
}
```

You can find the same code here:
[bowlingScoreCalculator.js](https://github.com/atahanozer/ProgrammingChallenges/blob/master/bowlingScoreCalculator.js)